# SQL - Two table data to be merged as one table

Tags: sql

Question: Write a SQL query for the below scenario

TableA

| cola |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

TableB

| colb |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Expected result:

| TableA.cola | TableB.colb |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

I started learning SQL and came across this question.

Tried inner join but still not getting the expected results.

Comment: What is the reason for aligning 1 & 4, but not 1 & 5 (for example)?

Comment: Please, provide your own code which is not working but is showing that you tried to solve the task.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: Select cola, colb from tablea,  tableb where cola = colb -3. :)

Answer (score 0):

To combine Tables you need to use INNER JOIN.
INNER JOIN requires an identical Column between TableA and TableB.
E.G. An ID
It would look like this:

```
SELECT TableA.cola,
       TableB.colb 
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB 
ON (TableA.ID = TableB.ID)
```

Depending on the type of SQL you are using (Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL,...) the syntax may vary.

In general it's not best practise to just join two columns, which have no correlation.
Also next time please give use an example Code so we have more context.

Comment: there is no columns called ID right? then it wont run